# Why is infinity = 0x3f3f3f3f?

Tags: c, infinity

In some situations, one generally uses a large enough integer value to represent infinity. I usually use the largest representable positive/negative integer. That usually yields more code, since you need to check if one of the operands is infinity before virtually all arithmetic operations in order to avoid overflows. Sometimes it would be desirable to have saturated integer arithmetic. For that reason, some people use smaller values for infinity, that can be added or multiplied several times without overflow. What intrigues me is the fact that it's extremely common to see (specially in programming competitions):

```
const int INF = 0x3f3f3f3f;
```

Why is that number special? It's binary representation is:

```
00111111001111110011111100111111
```

I don't see any specially interesting property here. I see it's easy to type, but if that was the reason, almost anything would do (0x3e3e3e3e, 0x2f2f2f2f, etc). It can be added once without overflow, which allows for:

```
a = min(INF, b + c);
```

But all the other constants would do, then. Googling only shows me a lot of code snippets that use that constant, but no explanations or comments.

Can anyone spot it?

Comment: Do you have any concrete example of this being used in a generic context (and not within a specialized algorithm where it might make sense)?

Comment: I tagged this as C since a quick Google search finds only C code that uses that constant. Feel free to retag.

Comment: @Mat: For example, take any algorithm that computes shortest paths in a graph. The distance to the unreachable vertices from the starting vertex is theoretically infinity. You need some way to represent that (but using floating point would be an overkill).

There could be examples of very different algorithms that use this. I gave a specific example, but the technique is handy whenever you would write "infinity" in pseudocode.

Comment: Specific examples, not "this could hypothetically be used". You claim these are extremely common, please link to some real-world examples.

Comment: @Mat: Sorry, I think my claim was indeed too strong. This may be uncommon in the "real-world", but they are still "extremely common" in programming competitions: http://goo.gl/PMCUNL

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found some evidence about this [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&u=http://blog.csdn.net/hzh_0000/article/details/9468377) ([original content](http://blog.csdn.net/hzh_0000/article/details/9468377) in Chinese); the basic idea is that 0x7fffffff is problematic since it's already "the top" of the range of 4-byte signed ints; so, adding anything to it results in negative numbers; 0x3f3f3f3f, instead:

- is still quite big (same order of magnitude of 0x7fffffff);
- has a lot of headroom; if you say that the valid range of integers is limited to numbers below it, you can add any "valid positive number" to it and still get an infinite (i.e. something `>=INF`). Even `INF+INF` doesn't overflow. This allows to keep it always "under control":

  ```
  a+=b;
  if(a>INF)
      a=INF;
  ```
- is a repetition of equal bytes, which means you can easily `memset` stuff to `INF`;
- also, as @Jörg W Mittag noticed above, it has a nice ASCII representation, that allows both to spot it on the fly looking at memory dumps, and to write it directly in memory.

Comment: It is the largest byte with the `memset` and `INF+INF` properties, because `2*0x40404040` is 0x80808080 > 0x80000000, which is one more than the max 32 bit int.

Answer (score 20):

I may or may not be one of the earliest discoverers of 0x3f3f3f3f. I published a Romanian article about it in 2004 (http://www.infoarena.ro/12-ponturi-pentru-programatorii-cc #9), but I've been using this value since 2002 at least for programming competitions.

There are two reasons for it:

- 0x3f3f3f3f + 0x3f3f3f3f doesn't overflow int32. For this some use 100000000 (one billion).
- one can set an array of ints to infinity by doing `memset(array, 0x3f, sizeof(array))`

Answer (score 12):

`0x3f3f3f3f` is the ASCII representation of the string `????`.

Krugle finds 48 instances of that constant in its entire database. 46 of those instances are in a Java project, where it is used as a bitmask for some graphics manipulation.

1 project is an operating system, where it is used to represent an unknown ACPI device.

1 project is again a bitmask for Java graphics.

So, in all of the projects indexed by Krugle, it is used 47 times because of its bitpattern, once because of its ASCII interpretation, and not a single time as a representation of infinity.